# Effects of updating Google webstore manifest file on OAuth permissions

Tags: google-apps-marketplace

I have a private app that is installed for a bunch of clients by their domain admins.  Our company name recently changed and I wanted to update the information for the app.  If I upload a new manifest file that changes the app name, but has the same api_console_project_id, will this require existing companies to reinstall/re-auth the app?  This is an "App" type, not an "Extension". It uses an OAuth server-to-server communication flow.

Related question.  If I do not have the original manifest file, can I start with the one that is contained within the main.crx file that I can download?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own mock users and testing this?

Comment: Not on a completely separate app.  I'm trying to get a deeper understanding how it's supposed to work.